# Getting Quicktime dimensions

Tags: objective-c, macos, desktop-application, quicktime

I'm having trouble with what I thought would be a simple task.

Is there a way to find the dimensions of a Quicktime file (possibly some sort of QT Media Attribute)?

I've been looking through the documentation and have yet to find something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSSize movieOriginalSize = [(NSValue*)[_movie attributeForKey:QTMovieNaturalSizeAttribute] sizeValue];
```